# How can I perform start command in PowerShell same as I do in CMD?

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe, process, exec

When I use `start` command in CMD it opens second CMD window with the same state (same location and same virtual environment). But I cannot do it in PowerShell. Is there any command for it in PowerShell?

Comment: `start` (alias for Start-Process) should work. What command did you run and what error did you get?

Comment: it didn't show the name of virtual environment in the new window so i thought it is not inside it. Turns out it is just not showing it. Thanks for answering

Comment: don't spam tags like that. Tags with versions are only for issues specifically related to that version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
start powershell
```

should do what you want.

Comment: One more thing if you don't mind. I unchecked "Quick edit" button in properties because it was freezing PowerShell. But now i have to press ctrl+M every time i want to scroll or select a text. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: @KyokoSasagava that's a different question.you need to post a different one. But the quick answer is no, you must change to a different terminal like Windows terminal